# Doxygen generates incorrect LaTeX code over private union attribute

Tags: latex, doxygen

Given the following C++ code

```
class Foo {
  private:
    union { int x; char y; } v;
  public:
    int get_int() { return v.x; }
};
```

and a standard configuration file, except for `EXTRACT_PRIVATE=YES`, doxygen version 1.8.6 is generating incorrect LaTeX code for the private attributes of `Foo`. More precisely, the relevant fragment of the tex document is following:

```
\hypertarget{unionFoo_1_1@0_a16eddb7296c37d91335845d7b847c6b3}{\>int {\bfseries x}\\
\hypertarget{unionFoo_1_1@0_ae4b5d1d732df4608dbc4871c55b7f4b2}{\>char {\bfseries y}\\
```

where the second argument of `\hypertarget` is lacking a closing brace `}`.

Setting `EXTRACT_ALL=YES` in addition to `EXTRACT_PRIVATE=YES` results in a correct output. Is the behavior above a bug in Doxygen, or should I use `EXTRACT_PRIVATE=YES` only when `EXTRACT_ALL=YES` too? The documentation is not very clear on a potential dependency between the two options, and if it is the case, maybe Doxygen should at least warn about inconsistencies.

Comment: Problem is still present in the current version of doxygen (1.8.7). I think this must be a bug. Can you file a bug report?

Comment: @albert: Done (https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=733605)